# Media query conditions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to make media query conditions for Responsive csss..

```
@media (max-width: 480px) and (max-width:640px)
```

Please let me know it is correct syntax , because this one not satisfying conditions.

Comment: What don't you understand?  Did you check documentation?

Comment: What does the OP want to achieve? What are his conditions? Besides that, this question is asked so many times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the below.**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px), screen and (max-height: xxxpx) {
  Your CSS
}
```

You can also read the below for further clarity.

> http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0

*PS: xxxpx is a dummy value where you can enter your values.*